# Corrupt framework-res.apk causes boot loop in KitKat 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, fastboot, unbricking, side-loading

My device is soft bricked due to a corrupt **framework-res.apk**, it’s stuck in a boot loop but it can be put in recovery mode.

In recovery it gives the option to install updates via `adb sideload` and the SD card. Also it has the `fastboot` mode.

I flowed some tutorials and created this [update.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbrqfof6dp0puln/update.zip?dl=0) file with the original **framework-res.apk**

[image]

**updater-script**

```
ui_print("Installing...");
show_progress(0.1, 0);
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/system");
package_extract_dir("system", "/system");
show_progress(0.1, 10);
show_progress(0.2, 0);
show_progress(0.2, 10);
set_perm_recursive(0, 0, 0755, 0644, "/system/framework/framework-res.apk");
ui_print("Done!")
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/system");
```

Running `adb sideload update.zip` from my computer transfers the file to the device but after that the device shows a message saying Error and "Installation aborted" without any detail of what could be the problem.

With `fastboot update update.zip` it shows

```
ERROR: could not clear input pipe; result e000404f, ignoring...
ERROR: could not clear output pipe; result e000404f, ignoring....
archive does not contain 'android-info.txt'
error: update package 'update.zip' has no android-info.txt
```

The device seems to be a MT6572 MediaTek (http://mundomint.com/mint-140/)

These are the ROMs that I've found for similar devices but haven tried any yet.

- [Mint 135](http://www.needrom.com/download/mint-135/)
- [Mint 145](http://www.needrom.com/download/mint-145/)

Comment: Is your recovery custom or stock?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman stock

Comment: On most devices, stock recovery won't install ZIPs that are not signed by the OEM.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I see, I'll try to find a compatible custom recovery